# Post right-click event using CGPostMouseEvent

Tags: objective-c, macos, mouseevent

I am trying to write a script that will be able to right-click on OS X 10.11.5. I have been using the Foundation framework on Objective-C to accomplish this. So far, I have been able to successfully left-click.

The script below is able to left click using `CGPostMouseEvent`, the documentation for which can be found in [CGRemoteOperation.h](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder/blob/master/blocks/QuickTime/include/msw/CGRemoteOperation.h).

The comments mention that I need a `boolean_t` for the final parameter in CGPostMouseEvent. I am not sure what that means, however I have tried the following combinations of params to no avail:

> (pt, 1, 1, 0, 1) 
> (pt, 1, 1, (0, 1)) 
> (pt, 1, 1, 2)

What is the proper final parameter for CGPostMouseEvent to trigger a right-click?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSUserDefaults *args = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // grabs command line arguments -x and -y
    //
    int x = [args integerForKey:@"x"];
    int y = [args integerForKey:@"y"];


    // The data structure CGPoint represents a point in a two-dimensional
    // coordinate system.  Here, X and Y distance from upper left, in pixels.
    //
    CGPoint pt;
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;


    // This is where the magic happens.  See CGRemoteOperation.h for details.
    //
    // CGPostMouseEvent( CGPoint        mouseCursorPosition,
    //                   boolean_t      updateMouseCursorPosition,
    //                   CGButtonCount  buttonCount,
    //                   boolean_t      mouseButtonDown, ... )
    //
    // So, we feed coordinates to CGPostMouseEvent, put the mouse there,
    // then click and release.
    //

    CGPostMouseEvent(pt, 1, 1, 1);
    CGPostMouseEvent(pt, 1, 1, 0);


    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `CGPostMouseEvent` is deprecated in Mac OS 10.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGPostMouseEvent` uses varargs to pass the state of buttons other than the left mouse button. The `mouseButtonDown` parameter indicates only whether or not the left mouse button is down. The state of other buttons should be passed after `mouseButtonDown`, in the varargs portion of the function signature. For the `buttonCount` argument you'll need to pass the total number of button states you're passing, including the left button.

The following sequence should post a mouse down event followed by a mouse up event for the right mouse button.

```
CGPostMouseEvent(pt, 1, 2, 0, 1);
CGPostMouseEvent(pt, 1, 2, 0, 0);
```

That said, `CGPostMouseEvent` has been deprecated for some time. Its replacement, `CGEventCreateMouseEvent` combined with `CGEventPost`, is easier to use.